# Error ocurred while parsing request parameters (Parse error 783)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, parse-error

I am building an api and my route for POST (create) is /api/v1/studios

The controller

```
def create
  @studio = Studio.new(studio_params)

  if @studio.save
    render json: @studio, status: :created, location: @studio
  else
    render json: @studio.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private
 def studio_params
     params.permit(:name)
 end
```

When i try to create an instance through curl ->

```
curl -X POST -v http://localhost:3000/api/v1/studios -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"studio1"}'
```

All i get is this errori wrote on the title.

```
Parsing error, could not resolve host: studio1}'
```

and in the development.log i get:

ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (783: unexpected token at ''{name:Disney}''):

Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

'{name:Disney}'

Comment: Can you show the error as it appears in your `development.log`?

Comment: I'm not sure how that `curl` command generates that error. It isn't really possible if your shell isn't completely wonky.

Comment: I have added the (i think) relevant error information on the development.log. Also, maybe my shell is wonky? i'm using postgres as database

Comment: Database is irrelevant. Where are you running that `curl` command? Can you also focus on this command and this command alone? You keep posting data that doesn't match the command in question.

Comment: I'm running curl on Git CMD on windows. I also ran " curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/studios " and it runs just fine.

Comment: Isn't Git CMD actually bash? I'm not sure if the single quotes vs. double quotes is an issue in that environment. In regular bash it isn't. In CMD it might be.

Comment: I don't really understand how it works, but you were on the money... somehow. Instead of using my Git CMD i used the Git bash through VS Code, i copied/pasted the curl command here in the bash and i got the error. I wrote it again, instead of copying/pasting and it worked. I am now able to add records with curl command. Thank you for your help, got it working now.
I cant really set your answer as accepted though, as you just commented here. If you answer below i'll do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that `curl` command is what you're running, then there's likely an issue with how your shell is processing the various quotes. That's in `bash` format, so if your shell doesn't adhere to that standard you'll get inexplicable syntax errors.